# Erro ao redirecionar para uma pagina jsf dentro de um bean

Tags: jsf, filter, redirect

(RESOLVIDO) Erro ao redirecionar para uma pagina jsf dentro de um ManagerBean.
Tenho uma aplicação em Java EE, e quero validar dentro do construtor de LoginBean (ViewScope) para redirecionar para minha página principal se já existir uma sessão aberta e válida para aquele navegador.

Consigo recuperar a sessão, verifico se ela é válida com sucesso, mas não consigo redirecionar antes de abrir a tela de login.

É retornado o seguinte erro:

```
Cannot call sendRedirect() after the response has been committed
```

Código do bean

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class LoginBean implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3654371476703737165L;

    public String testarSessaoLogada() throws IOException {
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest();
        HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);

        LoginControle loginControle = (LoginControle) session.getAttribute("loginControle");

        if (loginControle.getControleSessaoBean() != null && session != null) {
            SessaoLogada sessaoLogada = loginControle.getControleSessaoBean().buscarSessaoLogada(session.getId());
            if (sessaoLogada != null) {
                if (sessaoLogada.getUsuario().getTipo().equals("Cliente")) {
                    FuncoesUtils.redirect("");
                } else {
                    try {
                        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect("privado/controle.jsf");
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        try {
                            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect("privado/controle.jsf");
                        } catch (IOException ex) {
                            Logger.getLogger(LoginBean.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return "";
    }
}
```

Na página login.html tem o seguinte código que tem a funcionalidade de carregar a função que testa se já existe uma sessão logada para aquele browser...

O erro ocorre justamente quando tenta redirecionar

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect("privado/controle.jsf");
```

Precisava de descobrir o erro ou até uma dica para fazer esse redirecionamento de outra forma....
Desde já um muito obrigado.

***Resolução:***

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8399045/conditional-redirection-in-jsf

Apenas ao invés de carregar a função num componente da tela carreguei a mesma no antes do h:body.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
    <h:head>
       ...
    </h:head>
    <f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{loginBean.testarSessaoLogada()}" />
    <h:body>
        ...
```

Obrigado a todos q me ajudaram...

Answer (score 1):

Se a chamada estiver sendo realizada através de um `actionListner` ou um `action`, no próprio método você poderá retornar uma string com o valor **privado/controle.jsf**, se necessário um redirect get para atualizar a URL **privado/controle.jsf?faces-redirect=true**

```
public String testarSessaoLogada() throws IOException {
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest();
    HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);

    LoginControle loginControle = (LoginControle) session.getAttribute("loginControle");

    if (loginControle.getControleSessaoBean() != null && session != null) {
        SessaoLogada sessaoLogada = loginControle.getControleSessaoBean().buscarSessaoLogada(session.getId());
        return isClienteLogado(sessaoLogada) ? "" : "privado/controle.jsf";
    }

    return "";
}

private boolean isClienteLogado(SessaoLogada sessao){
    return sessao != null && sessao.getUsuario().getTipo().equals("Cliente");
}
```

Comment: obrigado pela resposta @Otávio , mas o problema que queria chamar esta ação ao renderizar a página, tentei colocar a mesma função no construtor...mas o erro também persistiu... o objetivo é verificar antes de carregar o login, verificar se existe uma sessão logado no navegador e redireciono para pagina de controle. Então só carrego o login se não existir sessão logado no navegador.